# Identify single SOLine item

Tags: acumatica

I have to update the custom field column in SOLine. However, I have multiple line items with the same Inventory and Warehouse selected. Is there a way I can find a single line item still?

Both the line items are marked for PO.

1. I need to identify a single line item where two different POs are created but the costs are different.
2. I need to identify a single line item where same POs are created but the costs are different.

Comment: Can you expand on your question to give greater clarity of the data flow in the system? SOLine holds a reference to an associated POLineNbr and PONbr.

Comment: SOLine and SOLineSplit should have the PO order information. If a single line is being fulfilled from 2 POs i think SOLineSplit is what you want to look at if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: That worked. SOLine do not have PO order information. It is SPLineSplit has all the PO Order and Receipt information. Thank you Brendan.

Comment: @Krunal From my understanding SOLine does hold information for PO's, just not in the context you needed.

Comment: May be you are right, but when I see SOLine DAC, it has OrigPOType and OrigPONbr field commented. Not sure if there is anywhere they get it from.

Comment: @Krunal Now I'm curios and will have to look further into this as there is data in those fields on demo installs.